# How to get the current testcase name in test-unit?

Tags: ruby, watir, testunit

example:

```
def setup
end

def teardown
end
```

How do I get the current case name in the setup method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.3, you can do something like this:

```
def setup
  puts self.__name__
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the unit test that ships with ruby 2.1.5 it seems to be:

```
def setup

   p method_name

end
```